# How do I add jQuery (online or offline) to my HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html; for some reason it is not working.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8" />
                        <title></title>
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">

                        </script>
                    </head>
                        <body>
                            <div id="container">
                                <h2></h2>
                            </div>
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $("h2").html("Hello there!");
                                });
                            </script>
                        </body>
            </html>
```

I am new to jQuery so sorry if I am making a blatantly ignorant mistake.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice? And what you posted works fine for me.

Comment: No clue; but if I remove one -- nothing is fixed.

Comment: But I am connected to the internet -- so shouldn't it still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `src` attribute from the script block:

```
  <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("h2").html("Hello there!");
          });
  </script>
```

This is because otherwise your browser will use the script specified in the `src` attribute rather than in its containing block

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not sure why that works -- but thank you!

Comment: Regarding "not sure why that works"....  It works because: now you've removed the SRC attribute it is a script block -  the code inside will be run as javascript; if you have a SRC attribute the the actual source file will be used and nothing in between the tags. Its one or the other. You have correctly included the jquery library in the head of your document, I'd suggest moving your script block into a separate file, say called "site.js" for example, and then including that file in the head too. When you learn more you can start compiling those two files into a single one, and much more...